# Protbuf-net Compiling to DLL string[] causing corrupt dll

Tags: c#, serialization, dll, unity-game-engine, protobuf-net

Here is my code:

```
using ProtoBuf;

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(500, typeof(SampleClassDrv))]
public class SampleClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int theInt;
    [ProtoMember(2)] public string[] items;
    public SampleClass(){}
    public SampleClass(int c) {this.theInt = c;}
}

[ProtoContract]
public class SampleClassDrv : SampleClass
{
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int theOtherInt;
    public SampleClassDrv(){}
    public SampleClassDrv(int b):base(1){this.theOtherInt=b;}
}
```

To compile my DLL I run the following code:

```
RuntimeTypeModel rModel = TypeModel.Create();
rModel.AllowParseableTypes = true;
rModel.AutoAddMissingTypes = true;

rModel.Add(typeof(SampleClass), true);
rModel.Add(typeof(SampleClassDrv), true);
rModel.Compile("MySerializer", "MySerializer.dll");
```

Finally I should be able to initialize by RuntimeTypeModel from the dll like so:

```
MySerializer serializer = new MySerializer();
serializer.Serialize(stream, object);
```

But Unity throws the following exception

```
Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information.
[...]
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
```

Interestingly enough if I go back and remove the line

```
[ProtoMember(2)] public string[] items;
```

It works as expected...

It is also worth noting the RunTimeModel works as expected if used after adding the classes instead of attempting to use dll.

My environment:

- Unity3D 4.3.4
- Protobuf-net r668
- using protbuf-net.dll in Full/unity

I would greatly appreciate if someone could point out the error in my ways.

**EDIT**

From the suggestion by Flamy I changed form string[] to List

```
[ProtoMember(2)] public List<string> items;
```

Sadly the error still persists.

**Another Note**

Also I decided to use a dll decompiler to see what is going on. I was not able to decompile the dll until the "string[] items" variable was removed.

**SOLVED**

I think it is related to some issue with compiling the DLL with Unity3D.

When I created the project in Visual Studios with the code I showed above everything seems to be working as expected. Which is a relief as this seems like it would be a huge issue if protobuf could not serialize `string[]`.

I followed the article provided by BCCode to setup the visual studio project and compile the DLLs.

Now all I need to do is create the dll with my large scale project! *Fingers Crossed*

Thanks everyone for their help!

Comment: This probably is irrelevant to your issue, but as I understand it, `theOtherInt` will shadow `theInt` in the base class. If this is representative of the actual classes, you may want to change the member indices of the derived class such that they don't collide with those of the base class.

Comment: I can't find anywhere where this is explicitly stated, but it does stand to reason. Perhaps @MarcGravell could verify.

Comment: I was under the impression that the index only needs to be unique per class bases, but if you are correct that is a big bug in my code and I will update my actual code to reflect your suggestion to be safe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your references correct? 
%project dir%\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp.dll

Also take a look here:
http://purdyjotut.blogspot.com/2013/10/using-protobuf-in-unity3d.html?m=1

Comment: Developing on the Mac and references are handle by Unity. I think they are correct. Let me know if I am just lacking some knowledge on this. Going to run through that article now. Thanks!

Comment: Went through the article and turns out I used a similar one when starting, but nothing seems different to what I have done outside the environment. So I'm going to jump on windows and attempt to compile the dll there.

Comment: I marked your's as solution as it led me to the correct answer. Updated the problem with details... it was some issue with compiling the dll in Unity3d. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Serilizing array of strings using Binary serilization or a serilization method that uses binary format (protobuff in this case) will always result in so many issues. The reason is String by itself is an array of chars,which doesnt have a defined size, meaning it dont know where one string ends and the next starts... Usually we serialize string array one by one instead of the whole array.  so I advice you to to use a property which does that (hopefully protobuff accepts attributes on properties!)  or create a list of strings instead (though i haven't tested yet it should work!)

Comment: I attempted your suggestion and changed string[] to List<string> but no luck. Thanks for the try!

Comment: `String[]` is implicitly converted to a repeated value, and are usually safe to use in Protobuf-Net. They are treated no differently than `List<string>`.

Comment: Also note that the actual serialization works fine until compiled to a dll.